# Run Nutch on existing Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, nutch

We have a Hadoop cluster (Hadoop 0.20) and I want to use Nutch 1.2 to import some files over HTTP into HDFS, but I couldn't get Nutch running on the cluster.

I've updated the **$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop** script to add the Nutch jars to the classpath (actually I've copied the classpath setup from **$NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch** script without the part that adds the $NUTCH_HOME/lib/* to the classpath) and then I tried running the following command to inject URLS:

`hadoop jar nutch*.jar org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector -conf conf/nutch-site.xml crawl_path urls_path`

but I got `java.lang.RuntimeException: x point  org.apache.nutch.net.URLNormalizer not found.`

The **$NUTCH_HOME/conf/nutch-site.xml** configuration file sets the property

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.jar.unpack.pattern</name>
    <value>(?:classes/|lib/|plugins/).*</value>
</property>
```

as workaround to force unpacking of the /plugin directory as suggested at: [When nutch is run on hadoop > 0.20.2 (or cdh) it will not find plugins because MapReduce will not unpack plugin/ directory from the job's pack (due to MAPREDUCE-967)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-937?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab#issue-tabs) but it seems that for me it didn't work.

Has anybody encountered this problem? Do you have a step by step tutorial on how to run Nutch on existing Hadoop?

Thanks in advance,

mihaela

Answer (score 4):

Finally I ran Nutch MapReduce jobs (Injector, Generator and Fetcher) using the bin/hadoop script with no modification with respect of Nutch.
The problem is with `org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar` class (the class which runs a hadoop job jar when calling `hadoop jar <jobfile> jobClass`) that adds to the classpath from the job jar file only the `classes/` and `lib/` subdirectories and Nutch jobs have a `plugins` subfolder also which containes the plugins used at runtime. I tried overriding the property `mapreduce.job.jar.unpack.pattern` to value `(?:classes/|lib/|plugins/).*` so that the RunJar class add also the plugins to the classpath but it didn't work.
After looking in Nutch code I saw that it uses a property `plugin.folders` which controls where can be found the plugins. So what I have done and it worked was to copy the plugins subfolder from the job jar to a shared drive and set the property `plugin.folders` to that path each time I run a Nutch job. For example:

```
 hadoop jar <path to nutch job file> org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher -conf ../conf/nutch-default.xml -Dplugin.folders=<path to plugins folder> <segment path>
```

In the `conf/nutch-default.xml` file I have set some properties like the agent name, proxy host and port, timeout, content limit, etc.

I have also tried creating the Nutch job jar with the plugins subfolder in the lib subfolder and then setting the `plugin.folders` property to value `lib/plugins` but it didn't work....

Answer (score 0):

I ran Nutch on an existing hadoop cluster modifying the bin/nutch script and then copying the nutch config files on the hadoop folders, modifying the TS and NS parameters. Did you try it that way?

Comment: No, because I found another solution. Can you be more specific? What are TS and NS parameters and what files have you copied on hadoop installation, and what have you added to the nutch script? If I have time may be I will try that way too. Thanks